# Multiple scala versions in the same project

Tags: scala, jvm

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I didn't hit on the magic keyword while searching.

I have a  project where I pull in various dependencies. One of them ([jooq](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-scala)) depends on scala 2.10, whereas my application depends on scala 2.11.x.

Although everything "works", I would like to understand better what are the runtime implications of doing something like this? How will the JVM resolve the different dependencies, and what type of overhead could I be looking at?

I am trying to determine if it's worthwhile to fork jooq, and compile it against 2.11 (assuming it will compile and work under 2.11).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala is not binary compatible between major versions (2.10 to 2.11 for example). This means that there are no guarantees that a library that is compiled for Scala 2.10 will work in a project using 2.11. You might be lucky enough that it works, but I would definitely not depend on that luck for any important codebase.

This is the reason why Scala libraries always has got the library version in their name and why SBT has got special syntax for dependencies to get the right library build for the Scala version used.

On a side note Martin Odersky (Scalas "father") has been proposing a solution to this problem during the year, storing an intermediate representation along with the byte code to allow automagical recompilation to a newer Scala version.

Comment: Thank you. In a related note, are there considerations for minor versions (e.g. 2.11.4 to 2.11.5) as well?  It would take a lot of cat herding to keep minor versions inline across versions.

Comment: There used to be before 2.10.

Answer (score 3):

You have the possible danger of runtime exceptions.

As Scala 2.10 and 2.11 are quite similiar the danger is not as big as it has been with 2.9 to 2.10 or 2.8 to 2.9 but it still is there and if you want to do something that is meant to be prodcution code, you definitly should try to raise jooq to 2.11.

Comment: [This should definitely be covered by jOOQ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4111)